# Export entire google site

Tags: java, google-sites

I am looking for a solution to export entire Google site form G suite.
I've tried : google-sites-liberation-1.0.4.jar, but it seems it doesn't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

try [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20150702123336/http://www.appservicer.com/batch-uploader-downloader-for-google-site)

> desktop application that automates the upload/download process of
>   large document repositories to/from Google Sites